# Why was the webpack.config.js entry used by Elixir Phoenix written as "'./js/app.js':"?

Tags: webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework

The name for a webpack entry is explained like so:
(https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#naming)

> **Naming**
>
> If a string or array of strings is passed, the chunk is named main. If an object is passed, each key is the name of a chunk, and the value describes the entry point for the chunk.

With the following examples provided:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  entry: {
    home: './home.js',
    about: './about.js',
    contact: './contact.js'
  }
};
```

The default Phoenix entry is:

```
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js'])
  },
```

Even though it is written as `'./js/app.js'` it's just a string which will be the name of the chunk, which threw me off for a bit and I had to consult the docs just to make sure there wasn't additional behavior or a change to the api I had missed.

I'm wondering if this is a new convention to name chunks according to the location of the entry points, or if this a preference the core team went with?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The entry name is not relevant in the default config, as `output.filename` is hardcoded to `app.js`.

You can change to `entry: {app: glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js'])}` and it should work the same.